# Docker run image with password file

Tags: bash, docker

I am trying to run image-inspector ( I know it is outdated, using for clamav test only) in a docker executing in bash.
with the parameters and one of them is -password-file ( password dumped into a file, there is not an option to do str password without file).
I am trying to run like:

> PWD_FILE="./pwdfile"
>
> docker run -p 8080:8080 openshift/image-inspector --scan-type=clamav
> --clam-socket=/var/run/clamd.socket -path "${MKDIR}" -username "${SP_ID}" -password-file "${PWD_FILE}" --image "${URI_DIGEST}"

Although, I am still getting `"error: File not found"` , for password file , even though the file is in the direct folder, when executing docker run. I have tried to create env variable for path inside Bash, tried to readlink of the file, variable to variable file. Not sure, if I am missing something documentation to image-inspector does not seem to say much...
image-inspector is executed for make a test of container ( one execution for container)
Does anybody have any experience or idea ?
Thank you!

Comment: I think you should mount directory with your password file.

Comment: @Saboteur thank you for pointing this out, after a many tries, the mount of "pwd" works great :) much appreciated, the final call to make image inspector run is like :


docker run --privileged -p 8080:8080 -v `pwd`:`pwd` -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl:/var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl -w `pwd`  openshift/image-inspector --scan-type=clamav --clam-socket=/var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl -path "${MKDIR}" -username "${SP_ID}" -password-file "./${PWD_FILE}" --image "${URI_DIGEST}